# ProgressView vs View inside ZStack behave differently

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have 2 views inside a ZStack. One is ProgressView() and another one is Circle().

In this ZStack, i have a green background color with onTapGesture event.

I notice that whenever i click on the ProgressView() the event of background color do not trigger but when i click on the Circle() it trigger the event of background color.

So why is that if both of these are on top of background color? i think it should not trigger the event for both views.

[image: my view]

```
       ZStack() {
        Color.green.ignoresSafeArea(.all)
            .onTapGesture {
                print("checked")
            }
        VStack() {
            ProgressView()
            Circle().frame(width: 30, height: 30, alignment: .leading)
        }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

They are actually not. Let's consider view hierarchy below (from view debug mode)

Shape is a native SwiftUI view and it is just rendered into the same backend as background and, actually by default not hit-testable.

ProgressView in contrary has UIKit backend, because it just representable of UIView, and all UIViews are added above native SwiftUI view (note, even if they are put into background). And by default this opaque UIView does not pass touch events through to SwiftUI.

That's it.

*changed to yellow color for better visibility

[image: demo]

Comment: how about other view like Text or TextField? this is the same condition right? i put another Text() view it behave just like this Circle.

Comment: So onTapGesture actually apply to entire frame even another view does not have onTapGesture

Answer (score 0):

As @Asperi wrote your VStack is in front of the Color View.
But one can use the modifier **allowsHitTesting**.
With this gesture are not processed by this view.

```swift
@State var text: String = "Hello World"
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack() {
                Color.green.ignoresSafeArea(.all)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        text = "Green tapped"
                    }
            
                VStack() {
                    ProgressView()
                    Circle().frame(width: 30, height: 30, alignment: .leading)
                    Text(text)
                }
                .allowsHitTesting(false)
                
            }
    }
```

Comment: This will not work and it will affect the inside Button and NavigationStack to behave unusually.

Comment: @tail I'm sorry I testet this before I posted it and it may surprise you it work. May it will affect NavigationStack but this wasn't the question.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a normal behavior.

However, if you want to get rid of this problem, you can always wrap your stack with a simple blank `onTapGesture{}`.

```
VStack {

}.onTapGesture{}
```

`onTapGesture{}` will get your stack rid of this problem, plus it will not affect your sub view and buttons inside the stack. Your `Button` inside the stack will behave normally.